# How to display the datas from two tables using search query?

Tags: php, search, mysqli, union

I need to display datas from particular based on the results.
I have two tables movies_info => has all movies info & tv_shows_info => has TV shows info. I have search box if i enter the search it should search from both the table and display the datas but the condition in the results if it has movie_id, it should show movie details and if the result has tv_show_id it should show tv-show details.

as of now i have used basic search to fetch datas from one table and i have tried of using two but its not working.

```
<?php
// sql query for retrieving data from database
        $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM `movies_info`";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_query);

 // SQL Query for filter
        if(isset($_POST['search_button']))
        {
            $value_to_search = $_POST['value_to_search'];

            // search in all table columns
            // using concat mysql function

            $search_query = "SELECT * FROM `movies_info` WHERE CONCAT(`movie_name`, `movie_original_name`, `release_year`, `movie_genre`, `movie_country`, `movie_stars`, `movie_director`) LIKE '%".$value_to_search."%'";

            //$search_query = "SELECT * FROM `movies_info`,`tv_shows_info` WHERE CONCAT(`movie_name`, `release_year`, `movie_genre`, `movie_country`, `tv_show_name`) LIKE '%".$value_to_search."%' GROUP BY `movie_id`";

            //$search_query = "SELECT * FROM `movies_info` UNION ALL `tv_shows_info` WHERE CONCAT(`movie_name`, `release_year`, `movie_genre`, `movie_country`, `tv_show_name`) LIKE '%".$value_to_search."%'";
            //$search_query2 = "SELECT * FROM `tv_shows_info` WHERE CONCAT(`tv_show_name`, `tv_show_start_year`, `tv_show_end_year`, `tv_show_genre`, `tv_show_country`) LIKE '%".$value_to_search."%'";
            //$search_query .= $search_query2;
            $search_result = filterTable($search_query);

        }

        else {
            $search_query = "SELECT * FROM `movies_info`";
            $search_result = filterTable($search_query);        
                //echo 'No Search Results Found';
        }

    ?>  

<!-- /w3l-medile-movies-grids -->
    <div class="general-agileits-w3l">
        <div class="w3l-medile-movies-grids">

                <!-- /movie-browse-agile -->

                      <div class="movie-browse-agile">
                         <!--/browse-agile-w3ls -->
                        <div class="browse-agile-w3ls general-w3ls">
                                <div class="tittle-head">
                                    <h4 class="latest-text">Search Results for : "<?php echo $value_to_search ?>"</h4>
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <div class="agileits-single-top">
                                            <ol class="breadcrumb">

                                              <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                                              <li class="active" style="text-transform:Capitalize;">Search Results </li>
                                            </ol>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                     <div class="container">
                                    <div class="browse-inner">

                                        <?php

                                            echo $search_result;

                                            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);

                                            for($i=1;$i<=$rowcount;$i++){
                                            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($search_result);


                                        ?>

                               <div class="col-md-2 w3l-movie-gride-agile">
                                         <a href="movie.php?movie_id=<?php echo $row['movie_id']; ?>" class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal"><img src="<?php echo $row['movie_image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $row['movie_name']; ?>" alt=" " />
                                         <div class="w3l-action-icon"><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                                    </a>
                                      <div class="mid-1">
                                        <div class="w3l-movie-text">
                                            <h6><a href="movie.php?movie_id=<?php echo $row['movie_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['movie_name']; ?></a></h6>                         
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mid-2">

                                            <p><?php echo $row['release_year']; ?></p>
                                            <div class="block-stars">
                                                <ul class="w3l-ratings">

                                                         <li> 
                                                          <span>IMDB <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $row['movie_rating']; ?> </span>
                                                         </li>

                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ribben two">
                                        <p>NEW</p>
                                    </div>  
                                                </div> <?php } ?>
                                </div>
```

as of now i can get the values from one table.,

My exact need is it can be Movie or TV-Show but i should get the datas from both the table if it is a movie it should show some particular info and if thats a TV-show it should show someother info.

Comment: @Priyank full code at https://gitlab.com/manigopal/showtime/blob/master/search_results.php

Comment: Search Query (PHP) @ https://gitlab.com/manigopal/showtime/blob/master/search_results.php

SQL @ https://gitlab.com/manigopal/showtime/blob/master/showtime.sql

Comment: Why not take the results in two different variables and checking whether empty or not loop both of them to form a table, first movies and then tv shows. – danish hashmi -- I tried this method only, @danishhashmi

Comment: Working code,but it does only shows movies_info table datas (SELECT movie_name,movie_original_name,release_year,universal_release_date,movie_genre,movie_country,movie_stars,movie_director as type FROM movies_info WHERE movie_name LIKE '%the%' OR movie_original_name LIKE '%the%') UNION (SELECT tv_show_name,tv_show_original_name,tv_show_start_year,tv_show_end_year,tv_show_genre,tv_show_country,tv_show_stars,tv_show_director as type FROM tv_shows_info WHERE tv_show_name LIKE '%the%' OR tv_show_original_name LIKE '%the%');
This query will give the perfect out put

Comment: the query works good at PHPmyAdmin 
but running PHP shows the following,
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected 'movie_name' (T_STRING) in

im getting this issue @Priyank

Comment: Search Results API 
@ https://gitlab.com/manigopal/showtime/blob/master/search_results_api_all.php

whats wrong with this code why it returns only null value ?

Comment: query works only at phpMyAdmin but in php query its not showing any value.,

Comment: Search Results API @ 
https://gitlab.com/manigopal/showtime/blob/master/search_results_api_all.php
-- only getting tv_shows datas alone., why not movies info too ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use prepared statements which you can use even if you are using the LIKE function in MySQL. Then you need to add spaces between the column names to prevent the values from being blended together like "star warsstar wars". This will cause a movie like "star wars to be a result when a user searches for "ss" which would be inaccurate.

```
$search_result = array(); 
$search_query = "SELECT * FROM `movies_info` WHERE CONCAT(`movie_name`,' ', `movie_original_name`,' ',`release_year`,' ',`movie_genre`,' ',`movie_country`,' ',`movie_stars`,' ',`movie_director`) LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')";
if($stmt = $db->prepare($search_query)){
        $stmt->bind_param('ii',$_SESSION['iidn_reference'],$o['parent_ref_id']);
        if($stmt and $stmt->execute()){
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                $search_result[] = $row;
            }
        }
}
```

After that, you could combine these tables with MySQL UNION but I strongly recommend just searching both tables and aliasing the table names to match.

```
SELECT 'movie' as `type`, `movie_id` as `id`, `movie_name` as `name`...
SELECT 'show' as `type`, `show_id` as `id`, `show_name` as `name`...
```

Comment: i use MySQLi ., can you guide me on it.

Comment: mysqli is more secure but not if you are using php to concat your query strings together. Here is a link to the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Check out this video playlist about using mysqli. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEbKji_pSZM&list=PLfdtiltiRHWEbLm0ErHe7HgEOVIO26R_o

This is the best channel on PHP i believe.